# PDF in Texmaker does not update changes

Tags: texmaker, viewers, linux

I just installed Linux Mint 17.1 (Cinnamon). I am using the embedded PDF-Viewer in Texmaker. Now when I make a quick build and click the arrow left of pdf-viewer, the old PDF without the changes stays in the preview. So it does not update/refresh. How can I fix this?
My debug-console ist not throwing any errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I can confirm it both on GNU/Linux and on Mac OS X.