# TeXmaker doesn't update PDFviewer for changes

Tags: texmaker, viewers

I am using a bash file to compile the .tex file constantly. The problem is though that the PDFviewer in TeXmaker doesn't update when the PDF file is changed.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) my guess is that TeXmaker is actually sending a signal to the PDF viewer after which is will reload. Thus is does not react to changes in the PDF on disk as some other PDF viewers do. You might have to figure out for your self how you send a similar signal to the viewer to cause it to update.

Comment: Try to add a line in your script to execute TeXmaker to preview the pdf. Maybe there is come optional argument to `texmaker` executable.

Comment: See also [PDF in Texmaker does not update changes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223582)